# sum values of a matrix by matching unique values in another matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, datatable, crosstab

I have two matrices (actually two RasterLayers with 1000s rows and columns). Say for example the matrices are A and B as below

```
A <- matrix(c(8, 3, 4, 7, 12, 5, 14, 7, 0), 3, 3, dimnames = list(paste0("Lat", 1:3), paste0("Lon", 1:3)))

A
     Lon1 Lon2 Lon3
Lat1    8    7   14
Lat2    3   12    7
Lat3    4    5    0

B <- matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 0), 3, 3, dimnames = list(paste0("Lat", 1:3), paste0("Lon", 1:3)))

B
     Lon1 Lon2 Lon3
Lat1    1    1    1
Lat2    1    1    3
Lat3    2    3    0
```

I am interested in creating a crosstab of sum of values in matrix A based on the entries of matrix B. For my example the end result should be a dataframe like this

```
C <- matrix(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 44, 4, 12), 4, 2, dimnames = list(seq(0:3), c("ID", "Sum")))

C

 ID Sum
1  0   0
2  1  44
3  2   4
4  3  12
```

How do I loop through one matrix (A) and sum values along the way based on a unique value in another matrix (B) and display the result as a table?

Comment: `tapply(A, B, FUN = sum)`

Comment: Or `aggregate(c(A) ~ c(B), FUN = sum)`. Or `xtabs(c(A) ~ c(B))`.

Comment: @Rui and Ritchie Thank you very much. Is there a way to remove the row 0   0? In my two RasterLayers there are always some cells with 0 in matrix A that'll exactly be 0 in matrix B as well.

Comment: Try `agg <- aggregate(c(A) ~ c(B), FUN = sum); agg[rowSums(agg != 0) != 0, ]`. Or `xt <- xtabs(c(A) ~ c(B)); xt[xt != 0]`.